# How to draw a line graph in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, linegraph

I am trying to draw a line graph in ASP.NET.  I want to import some data from an excel file and display them in a line chart on the browse.

So far I figured out how to import the data and display them in a grid.  Now I want to take it to the next step and draw a line graph using that data.

Please point me in the right direction to some guides on how to draw a line graph in ASP.NET (C# only).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [.NET Chart Controls](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/mschart)

[image]

A good getting started article: [Using Microsoft's Chart Controls In An ASP.NET Application: Getting Started - 4GuysFromRolla.com](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020203246/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/072209-1.aspx)

Or for a JavaScript solution use [gRaphaël—Charting JavaScript Library](http://g.raphaeljs.com/)

[image]

Comment: Dang. Ninja'd me by *seconds*, for the same answer. :p

Comment: Thank you for the information, this looks really helpful.  I believe this is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

If all you're after is a simple line graph, then rather than jumping at some third party libraries you can simply manipulate the length of an image, based on the data.

Something I have done a few times is take the data and turn it into a percentage, then make an images height (or width) that percent.

for example,

Say you have your data. Number of orders per day. your data may look like:

monday = 20
tuesday = 15
wednesday = 50
thursday = 30
friday = 10
saturday = 80
sunday = 3

Calculating the percentage for each day is simple. you would do something like:

Total sales = 203. And the formula [DaySales]/[TotalSales] * 100 will give you the percent for that day.

monday = 9.85% tuesday = 7.21%  wednesday = 24.03%  thursday = 14.42% friday = 4.80%  saturday = 38.46%  sunday = 1.44%

Simply set the image height/width to the appropriate day percentage and then you have yourself a nice little bar graph with accurate (within a pixel) lines

Answer (score -1):

Read about the [Graphics Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.aspx). It allows you to generate images. Getting these to show in a `<img>` element is another exercise.

Comment: I know that in html i can create a canvas and then draw lines directly with jquery, with asp.net would it not work similarly?  The <img> tag you refer to, would that be the same as a canvas?

Comment: No and no. You'll be drawing a bitmap with System.Drawing.Graphics, and then output that as a content of some image mime type, so that you can get an `<img>` element and point to your output with the `src` attribute.